# Docker can't find a script that I COPY to an image when I try to invoke it twice via /script.sh && /script.sh (but once works!)

Tags: docker, dockerfile

A simple example of what i'm trying to do involves a Dockerfile like this:

```
from ubuntu

COPY  script.sh /script.sh
RUN   chmod a+x /script.sh
```

And a script file like this:

/script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

    echo hi `date`
    sleep 1
    echo hi `date`
```

I build and run like this and everything is fine and dandy:

```
docker build -t client .
docker run   client  /script.sh
```

When I do the above I see  'hi' twice with the date.

Now, if I want to be told 'hi' four times, I would think I could do this:

```
docker run   client  /script.sh && /script.sh
```

But that fails with the error:

```
bash: /script.sh: No such file or directory
```

Very odd.. since i am providing the full path to /script.sh.. I wonder why bash can't find it.

For built-in commands I can  'chain' using the '&&'  operator.  For example this works fine:

```
docker run   client  /script.sh &&  echo it works
```

If anyone could enlighten me, I'd be very grateful !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command is parsed on the host into the `"docker run..." && /script.sh` with obvious results. You might want to rephrase it to say `docker run ... /bin/bash -c "/script.sh && /script.sh"`